# Как сопировать страницу с помощью python и bs4

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Видел, как чтобы не долбить сайт запросами, люди сохраняют страницу на компьютер и потом парсят её.
Пишу

```
req = requests.get(f'http://auto.ru/cars/vaz/all/on-credit')
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.content)
        with open('page.html', 'w') as file:
            file.write(soup)
```

Ругается, что не тот тип данных у переменной soup. Как все таки это сделать?

Comment: file.write(req.text)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: Ты не долби один раз отправь запрос и пользуйся им в программе сколько нужно.